# _ITERATOR DEBUG LEVEL confusion?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, debugging, opencv

I have decided to work from now on on RELEASE and not DEBUG anymore.

I have copied the same directories / paths / additional blabla of the Debug to the Release as well to get rid of the ""undefined ... problems""

But I still have the following errors / warnings:

```
Error   3   error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '1' in ex4.obj  C:\...\ex\qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj)
Warning 4   warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrtd.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library   C:\...\ex\MSVCRT.lib(cinitexe.obj)
Error   5   error LNK1319: 1 mismatches detected    C:\...\Win32\Release\\ex.exe    1
```

Could you help me to sort that out?

Comment: "I have copied the same directories / paths / additional blabla of the Debug to the Release" Why would you do that?  You should just have to set the new build type, then do full clean/rebuild.

Comment: @cmannett85 I had to do that because otherwise, it would give me undefined definition errors of lots of tools I'm using like the includes of opencv which will be undeclared for example. But with the Debug version, I was never having those undefined stuff errors.

Comment: That must be different problem.  The difference between debug and release builds from a Qt developer POV is essentially a difference in compiler flags and build output directory.  None of your includes, linked libraries, or paths should change.

Comment: They didn't change. It's just that I didn't find the ones of OpenCV when I switched to RELEASE. But the ones of Qt have changed, it's true.

Comment: Have you updated your link settings to pull in the release version of the standard library?  (Changing `/MDd` to `/MD`)

Comment: @simonc Please answer the question below. And thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change between Debug and Release builds with MSVC, you need to change which version of the C runtime you link to.  i.e. Either change `/MDd` -> `/MD` or `/MTd` -> `/MT`

Answer (score 0):

Mixing _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL in a project is sure recipe for disaster: you can get random-looking crashes, memory corruption and whatever. DO NOT GO THERE. The linker is kind to glag it for you in some cases, unfortunately lack of warnings may still leave you with problem.

The only real cure is to compile with uniform options. (Certainly including _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL but other settings also can lead to problems.)

The root of the problem is that the headers you include have #if parts so with differrnt settings you compile different code.  This is called *violation of ODR*, the one definition rule.  That punishes you with undefined behavior, and even no diagnostics is required.

An example, one part of code may think vector has 16 bytes in size and other 24 bytes. That an iterator has the pointer at offset 0 and other at offset 8.

Where mix is absolute must, you need carefully firewall parts of program, so that they never share objects from standard lib directly, are only tied by a light interface and everyone deal only with its private data.

Comment: Judging from his error messages, the mismatch is due to one of the libraries he's including. Specifically the C runtime, which is specified by `/MDd`; he needs to change this to `/MD`.